# Congratulations, lab bhattacharjee!

Tags: discussion, specific-user, celebration

Congratulations [lab bhattacharjee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33337/lab-bhattacharjee) on reaching 100k reputation!

We all appreciate your continued efforts on Math.SE.

Comment: Too bad I missed the exact day you reached 100k, which I think was 2 days ago.

Comment: We had a [celebration thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16859/congratulations-lab-bhattacharjee) that wasn't well-received and was later deleted. I suppose it's natural since 100K is no longer an unusual event or milestone for the site.

Comment: @AymanHourieh, oh, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Congratz anyway!

Comment: Congratulations, @lab ! The significance of passing $100$K doesn't diminish just because others have too! So I hope you feel a sense of pride in having persisted in answering so many questions, so much so, that you happened to garner more than $100$K That reflects a HUGE commitment and contribution to this site. I hope you  plan to keep up the good work!

Comment: Indeed, a hearty congratulations to lab, and many thanks for his contributions.

Comment: May I also add that I think @lab is one of the "fastest guns" around MSE land! I'd be interested to know the ratio of "first to answer": "number of posts answered"! I'm am amazed at the quality of his(?) answers given such speed in answering! (his?: Everyone seems to presume that lab is male. That may very well be, but where does that presumption come from?)

Comment: I think it is also interesting to note that lab made it to 100K very consistently over 2 years. Lab's rep curve is roughly a straight line over that time from 0 to 100k. I think consistency in life is an admirable quality.

Comment: All students lucky enough to have their questions answered by lab bhattacharjee have reason to be grateful. Lab has made great contributions to MSE.

Comment: Many learners, particularly me, have their doubts cleared (and learnt some cool tricks) because of @lab. So thanks again and congratulations.

Comment: Congratulations, a great achievement!

Comment: lab bhattacharjee is officially the unofficial prime minister of MSE.

Comment: Hearty Congratulations @lab !

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Sorry for being late, but I didn't get any notification about the existence of such a page:). It has really been (I believe it will remain) the best learning & rectifying online center for me. This is a place which always reminds me the ocean of knowledge that has remained unexplored   from my part and so prohibits all potential vanity of knowledge.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Congratulation. Your knowledge based effort is really impressive. I take my hat off for you. Greetings from Germany to India.